# How to get data from a yml file, to then return as a dictionary

Tags: python, pyyaml

I have a python function that will open a YAML file and read the data. The YAML file contains two api keys and a domain. I want to return each value in a dictionary so it can be used in the program. However I get the error

> "list indices must be integers, not str".

Should I just make the variables global, so it doesn't have to return anything?

The code is:

```
def ImportConfig():
    with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
        config = yaml.load(ymlfile)
        darksky_api = config['darksky']['api_key']
        gmaps_api = ['gmaps']['api_key']
        gmaps_domain = ['gmaps']['domain']
    return {'darksky_api_key': darksky_api, 'gmaps_api_key': gmaps_api, 'gmaps_domain': gmaps_domain }
```

What does it mean that the list indices must be integers? I thought curly brackets indicated a dictionary? Also is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does the YAML file look like?

Comment: darksky:
    api_key: abc12
gmaps:
    api_key: abc123
    domain: maps.google.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent of your yaml file if you type `['xy']` a the prompt of Python you create a list with one element and if you then index that with another string:

```
['xy']['abc']
```

you'll get that error.

You are missing `config` in line 5 and 6 of your program:

```
def ImportConfig():
    with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
        config = yaml.safe_load(ymlfile)
        darksky_api = config['darksky']['api_key']
        gmaps_api = config['gmaps']['api_key']
        gmaps_domain = config['gmaps']['domain']
    return {'darksky_api_key': darksky_api, 'gmaps_api_key': gmaps_api, 'gmaps_domain': gmaps_domain }
```

please note that using `load` in PyYAML is security risk and for your data you should use `safe_load()`.

Comment: Oh wow, yeah I am hahah. Im not sure how I didnt see that, thanks though. I was so confused!!! Thanks man.

Comment: Make sure you change the `load` into a `safe_load`, what I wrote in my update.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference?

Comment: If your input would not be 100% under your control in the future someone could insert tags in the YAML and execute arbitrary code on load. With `safe_load()` that is not possible and you could add loaders for specific classes only if ever needed, instead of allowing any tags, including those that could be malicious. In my `ruamel.yaml` (dirived from PyYAML) I give a warning if you forget about that.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense. This is just a little hobby/project for me and so it will only be for personal use, good to know though! Thanks.